# How to resize image when upload for all mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, react-native, mobile

I just build a sample react native project I a have a problem when original image I uploaded in server not fit all screen on another mobile screens (IOS, Android)

I need to resize the image according to each device resolution?

Please help me to solve this problem

[Androi Guides - Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

[Apple image size](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/)

Comment: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example It will help you to generate 9 patch images for different density devices

Answer (score 0):

try to set resizeMode stretch like this

```
<Image soure={image} style={{width:200, height:200, resizeMode:'stretch'}} />
```

Comment: I think it's not a best solution because original image does not display clearly on a large resolution

Comment: Use cover instead of stretch